# How to find gap in API response - JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter and scripting overall.

Here's my scenario - My response from the HTTP request generates data every second and the response gives the timestamp along with other data. I have to identify if there is any gap in the timestamp sequence just to identify if there is any gap in the data overall.

Example of my response is attached (timestamp highlighted).

How can I achieve this? The whole idea is that the data should be present for every second, and missing data needs to be identified.

Post Note - There will be thousands of rows depending on the start and end time I am passing in the request, but since JMeter limits the data row to 1000 rows only and my data is going to be more than that, how can I loop my request so that the end time passed in my previous request becomes the start date of my next request and the request becomes a 15 minute time range request which will generate 900 records.

Please let me know if more details is needed or if I don't make any sense.

Please see the attachment as well.

Any guidance will be really helpful.

Thank you!
Keshav[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW0nM.png)

I'm new to scripting so don't have much idea on how to proceed with this and how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good by parsing incomplete JSON by looking at [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) so I can only provide a generic answer:

1. You can create custom pass/fail criteria using [JMeter Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-assertions) in general and in your case [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) in particular
2. Response body can be fetched as `prev.getResponseData()` where `prev` stands for the **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
3. Once done you can use [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/xml/XmlSlurper.html) to extract `data` attribute values and store them into some form of [Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)
4. And finally iterate the array and check if the next item is 1 second ahead of the previous